# How to import eslint config into another directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, eslint

I'm struggling with importing my base config from one file to another.

Basically, I have a folder called configs and in this folder, I have all my base configs

```
- configs
  - eslint
    - eslint-next.js
    - eslint-nest.js
    - eslint-node.js
- data
  - src
    - user.ts
  - eslintrc.js
  - prettierrc
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
```

In file `data/eslintrc.js` I'm importing another file via

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["custom-nest-eslint-config"],
};
```

and the name in the `eslint-nest.js` file is the same `custom-nest-eslint-config`

I know that config works because when I hard copy it to `eslintrc.js` user.ts has highlights and errors, but when I'm extending nothing shows

What am I doing wrong?

Also in `eslintrc.js` when I'm passing the path to the file VS Code suggests the path correctly so it's visible